# How to get the value of user level RSP from a system call?

Tags: c

The RSP register points to the top of the current function's stack. When the user level program enters a system call, the user level RSP should be saved somewhere, so that it can be restored after the system call finishes. In the following code, I want to get the user level RSP from the system call.

I found there is a "usersp" field in "struct thread_struct", and I was expecting to get the user level RSP from there. However, the value of user level RSP got from there in the system call is different from that in the user level function. Why they are different, and how can I get the user level RSP from a system call?
I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 on x86 platform with Linux kernel 3.14.4.

```
void main(void){
       ...
       register unsigned long rsp asm("rsp");
       my_syscall();
       ...
}

void my_syscall(){
      /*the value of user_rsp is not equal to the value of USER_RSP in main()*/
      unsigned long user_rsp = current->thread.usersp; 
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38361742/2189500) can give you some ideas?